# git clone over HTTP does not show any output

Tags: git, http, clone, output

I have setup a git repo and wanted to access it through HTTP. Everything is fine, but when I do `git clone http://mygit/abc.git` it takes a while and completes. I do not see any "Counting objects ....." kind of prints. My repo clones fine.

See below.

Why is this so?

```
$ git clone http://mygit/abc.git
Cloning into abc...
$
$ ls
abc
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there *are* no objects yet?

What happens when you do a `git count-objects -v`?

Comment: `$ git count-objects -v 
 
count: 0

size: 0
in-pack: 2831376
packs: 1
size-pack: 672882
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0`

Comment: That's a very large repo! Both in terms of number of objects and the size. That certainly accounts for the 'taking a while part'. I'm uncertain why you're missing the additional output though.

Comment: what does the command `git remote -v` output? I have a hunch that you're inadvertently doing a symlink clone.

Comment: When I do the same over ssh, I get the output. I don't understand what is wrong with http. But I really want http so that I can give read-only access.

Comment: `$ git remote -v  
origin http://mygit/abc.git (fetch)  
origin http://mygit/abc.git (push)`